# How do I overlay spectra in an ACD/NMR Processor, version 12.01?

Tags: software, nmr-spectroscopy

I am having great difficulty getting spectra to overlay (the option doesn't even appear) after setting to new window mode and selecting each spectrum.

Comment: Did you know that you can submit a real [answer to your own qeuestion](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: I have moved your answer out of your question, since as the above comment suggests, it should be in the form of an answer.  You can add your own answer if you would like and I will delete the temporary one.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is running into the same issue, after selecting which spectra you would like to overlay go to series -> collect spectra and then select "manual offset" if you want to adjust the height.